# Error: No overload for method 'InsertBU' takes 6 arguments, while using Table Adapter in Dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset, tableadapter

I am using TableAdapter(say "SDM_Master_BUTableAdapter") inside DataSet(say "SDMDAL").
Below is the **Structure of Table Adapter**:

[image]

The "InsertBU" Stored Proc in above Table Adapter is used to Insert records from RadGrid into Database Table.
Below is the **Database Table Structure** in which I am Inserting the records from RadGrid:

[image]

Below is the **Insert Stored Procedure** I am using for inserting the records in above table:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SDM_Insert_BU]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @BUName as nvarchar(500),
    @BUShortName as nvarchar(500),
    @BUfoCompanyID as nvarchar(50),
    @BUfoStatusID as nvarchar(50),
    @BUAddressNo as nvarchar(50),
    @BURelationship as nvarchar(50)

    AS  
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @BUID as nvarchar(50)
    --SP to generate new ID 
    EXEC dbo.SDM_Assign_RunningNo
    @TableName='SDM_Master_BU',
    @NewID = @BUID OUTPUT

    INSERT INTO SDM_Master_BU (BUID, BUName, BUShortName, BUfoCompanyID, BUfoStatusID, BUAddressNo, BURelationship)
    VALUES (@BUID, @BUName, @BUShortName, @BUfoCompanyID, @BUfoStatusID, @BUAddressNo, @BURelationship)

    SELECT @BUID as BUID    
END
```

**.cs file code**, which call the "InsertBU" stored Proc from Table Adapter:

```
private SDM_Master_BUTableAdapter _BUTableAdapter = null;
    protected SDM_Master_BUTableAdapter Adapter
    {
        get
        {
            if (_BUTableAdapter == null)
                _BUTableAdapter = new SDM_Master_BUTableAdapter();

            return _BUTableAdapter;
        }
    }

        public string InsertBU(string BUName, string BUShortName, string BUfoCompanyID, string BUfoStatusID, string BUAddressNo, string BURelationship)
    {
        string BUID = Convert.ToString(Adapter.InsertBU(BUName, BUShortName, BUfoCompanyID, BUfoStatusID, BUAddressNo, BURelationship));
        return BUID;
    }
```

**aspx.cs page code**, calling .cs file "InsertBU()" function to insert records in RadGrid:

```
    public DataTable _dtBU;

    protected void rgBU_InsertCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _dtBU = SDM.BU.GetBU();
            GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;

            string BUName = (item["BUName"].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
            string BUShortName = (item["BUShortName"].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
            DropDownList clist = item.FindControl("ddlCompany") as DropDownList;
            string BUfoCompanyID = clist.SelectedValue.ToString();
            DropDownList slist = item.FindControl("ddlStatus") as DropDownList;
            string BUfoStatusID = slist.SelectedIndex.ToString();
            string BUAddressNo = (item["BUAddressNo"].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
            DropDownList rlist = item.FindControl("ddlRelationship") as DropDownList;
            string BURelationship = rlist.SelectedIndex.ToString();

            bool check = true;
            foreach (DataRow dr in _dtBU.Rows)
            {
                if (dr["BUfoCompanyID"].ToString() == BUfoCompanyID)
                {
                    check = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            //Insert BU
            if (check)
            {
                SDM.BU.InsertBU(BUName, BUShortName, BUfoCompanyID, BUfoStatusID, BUAddressNo, BURelationship);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox_simple("Insert Failed", "BU cannot be inserted.<br/> Reason: The record with the same value already exists.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLogger.LogException(ex, SPContext.Current.Web.Url.ToString() + "-" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString());
            MessageBox_simple("Error", "Error!<br/>Please print screen and submit ITS.<br/> Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
    }
```

When I try to run the same .aspx page, everytime I get below error:

> No overload for method 'InsertBU' takes 6 arguments

I read all the Stackoverflow articles related to this topic but those couldnt solve my issue. I am still working on this and almost checked every possible thing but still same error.
 
Please let me know what is wrong in my code ?
Please reply. 
Please forgive if the question is basic because I am new in Table Adapter functionality.

Comment: Did you check the code generated for SDM_Master_BUTableAdapter class?

Comment: There is miss match in no. of parameters and no of argument ... check no of parameters and argument

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Please see the Insert Stored Procedure, there I am declaring 6 parameters whose value will be passed from the form (using aspx.cs code) and in same Stored Procedure, see the Insert Query in which I am passing 7 parameters, that need to be inserted. This 7th column value is coming from another Stored Procedure (already defined there) and my DataBase Table has total no of columns = 8, in which 8th column is the ID column which is Primary key with identity as true. Please let me know what is missing ? Please reply